# wcslen or strlen should prevent infinite loop?

Tags: c++, string, string-length

This function count number of chars between the begging of string and terminating null character.

```
size_t wcslen(const wchar_t* sz)
{
    size_t l = 0;
    while (*sz++) ++l;
    return l;
}
```

Now if there is no terminating null character this functions should detect that or no? How they detect? Is there a limit for the loop and it is not an infinite indeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And how is the function to do that?  The definition of the
length is "until the terminating nul character".  A "safer"
version of the function might take an additional maximum length,
which would correspond to the length of the buffer where the
data was held.  But the use of nul terminated strings is
universal in C, and most of the time, if you're calling this
function, it's because the function calling you only gave you a
pointer, and you don't know the actual length of the buffer.

In practice, if the input doesn't have a terminating nul
character, you'll get a buffer overrun, reading memory beyond
the end of your buffer.  When doing so, sooner or later, you'll
either encounter a byte which contains a 0, and consider that
the end of your string, or you'll end up with an address which
isn't mapped to your process, and you'll crash.

Answer (score 2):

This function stop at the first 0 value, if there is no wchar_t with a 0 at the end of sz parameter, it will continue in the rest of the memory till a 0 value is reached

Comment: Or till (quoting @Joker_vD) "eventually sz will overflow, after which you'll try to dereference NULL which will get you an exception", isn't it?

Comment: As James Kanze says : if you don't reach a 0 byte, you'll reach an address not mapped to your process and it will crash

Answer (score 1):

If there is no null terminator for a string the behavior is undefined. You cannot tell what you will get.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the contract is that you supply a NUL-terminated string. If you don't, all bets are off and the behaviour of the function is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no null-terminator (though I have trouble imagining memory space all filled with garbage without any zeroes), then eventually `sz` will overflow, after which you'll try to dereference NULL which will get you an exception.

Comment: Depending on the system, it's more likely that you'll access unmapped memory before the address wraps.  (And there's no guarantee that dereferencing a null pointer will cause a crash, or that incrementing will eventually lead to a null pointer.  On older Intels, his function could quite possibly lead to an endless loop.)